# Rewrite the Euler equation $ax^2y''+bxy'+cy=0$ as $a \frac{d^2y}{dv^2}+(b-a)\frac{dy}{dv}+cy=0$ using the substitution $y=\ln x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

(The exercise says we can assume $x>0$). If $v=\ln x$, then we can solve for $x$ as a function of $v$, i.e.  $x=x(v)= e^v$. Furthermore, we know that $x$ is identical to all its (infinite) derivatives:

$$e^v = x \iff \frac{d^n x}{dv^n} = e^v $$

This implies

$$ae^v \frac{d^2y}{dv^2} + b \frac{dy}{dv} + cy=0$$

But I don't know how to show that $e^v=1+ \frac{dy}{dv}$.

Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dv}\frac{dv}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dv}\frac{1}{x}=\frac{dy}{dv}e^{-v},
$$
and
$$
\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{d}{dx}[\frac{dy}{dv}e^{-v}]=\frac{d^2y}{dv^2}e^{-2v}-\frac{dy}{dv}e^{-2v}.
$$
Plugging in the original equation, since $x^2=e^{2v}$ and $x=e^v$, the $x$'s cancel and you end up with an equation with constant coefficients
$$
a\left(\frac{d^2y}{dv^2}-\frac{dy}{dv}\right)+b\frac{dy}{dv}+cy=0
$$
which is the desired equation

Comment: I'm iffy on the Chain rule, so my confusion arose from this step: $d/dx[dy/dv]$. Is it legal to say $\frac{d}{dx}[\frac{dy}{dv}]=\frac{dv}{dx}\frac{d}{dv}[\frac{dy}{dv}]= \frac{dv}{dx}\frac{d^2 y}{dv^2}$?

Comment: Sure. You can look at $dy/dv$ as a function of $x$ via the intermediate quantity $v$ and the chain rule works normally.